# Getting "Authentication via SSL not supported." when calling PHP function ftp_login

Tags: php, ssl, ftp

I'm having issues with connecting to remote ftp server with PHP and SSL. I am using `ftp_ssl_connect` to at least connect to remote FTP server with SSL, but with no luck.

I'm getting

> ftp_login(): Authentication via SSL not supported.

I'm using these PHP lines.

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect($host);
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $user, $pw);
```

Indeed SSL is not supported for both (local, remote) machines. I have checked it with `php -i | grep "SSL Version"` and it returns Secure Transport. I think this is the problem. I would like to change it to OpenSSL but without reinstalling PHP as it was mentioned in other Stack Overflow questions. Is it possible?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Some relative code might help. Might be the server your connecting to. Also ftp with ssl is not the same as sftp.

Answer (score 0):

> Indeed SSL is not supported for both (local, remote) machines

If the server does not support TLS/SSL, there's nothing you can do about it on client (PHP) side.

---

And indeed the *"Authentication via SSL not supported"* seems to be an error message coming from the (tnftpd) FTP server:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7045410

---

Actually I do not think that you have a problem on client (PHP) side. Because were OpenSSL not built into PHP, your PHP script won't even run, as the `ftp_ssl_connect` function won't be available.

You would get:

> Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect() in ...